# MySQL to remove rows past the current date and transfer them to another table

Tags: mysql, database, sql-insert, sql-delete, delete-row

I was tasked to create a database for a gym system for my project, I need help on what MySQL query should I use for my program.

First query: Remove rows in the TBL_ACTIVEMEMBER where the END column date is past the current date.

Second query: Transfer and insert those removed rows into another table which is TBL_INACTIVEMEMBER.

So these are my tables:

1. TBL_ACTIVEMEMBER:

> ```
> +------+---------+--------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
> | AMID | GYMID   | INSTID | TYPE     | TERM     | START      | END        |
> +------+---------+--------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
> |    1 | 2021001 |   4502 | Gold     | 3 Months | 2021-12-18 | 2022-03-18 |
> |    2 | 2021003 |   4504 | Platinum | 3 Months | 2021-12-13 | 2022-03-13 |
> |    3 | 2021002 |   4502 | Silver   | 3 Months | 2022-01-15 | 2022-04-15 |
> |    4 | 2021004 |   4502 | Platinum | 5 Months | 2021-12-25 | 2022-05-25 |
> |    5 | 2021006 |   4503 | Silver   | 5 Months | 2021-12-18 | 2022-05-18 |
> |    6 | 2021007 |   4502 | Silver   | 1 Month  | 2021-12-24 | 2022-01-24 |
> |    7 | 2021008 |   4501 | Gold     | 3 Months | 2021-12-18 | 2022-03-18 |
> |    8 | 2021008 |   4503 | Platinum | 1 Month  | 2021-12-12 | 2022-01-12 |
> |    9 | 2021009 |   4502 | Silver   | 3 Months | 2022-01-08 | 2022-04-08 |
> +------+---------+--------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
> ```

2. TBL_INACTIVEMEMBER:

> ```
> +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
> +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | INAMID| int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
> | GYMID | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
> | END   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
> +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TBL_INACTIVEMEMBER (Column1, Column2, ColumnN) 
SELECT * FROM TBL_ACTIVEMEMBER where END < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

This will insert the required values into the table `TBL_INACTIVEMEMBER`. Change the column names as required.

Now to delete the inactive values from table `TBL_ACTIVEMEMBER`,

```
DELETE FROM TBL_ACTIVEMEMBER WHERE END < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```